# Adding header to action request and response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I add a HTTP header to all action calls in ASP.NET MVC. Looking at the IActionFilter but could I interact with the HttpRequestMessage instance if I was to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `IActionFilter`, you provide the `OnActionExecuted` method where you could do something like this:

```
void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Header-Name", "HeaderValue");
}
```

Comment: How can I extract the content or HttpRequestMessage from the ActionExecutedContext?

Comment: @MarioDennis That is a different question and you should post that as such. Questions answered in comment sections don't tend to help a lot of people.